# It is possible to run out of gas when calling bytes32[]?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, ether, gas

Is possible to run out of gas when calling `bytes32[]`, even when count e.g. 1k entries?

Answer (score 2):

There is no cost associated with calling `bytes32[]` off-chain. If you are using this data for your application, then the off-chain call is free.

If you are calling it on-chain, there will be a cost associated with each lookup and **therefore it will be possible to run out of gas**. To get each value of the array, you will need to loop through the array. The cost associated with the loop depends on  what you mean by "call". If you are doing minimal logic per loop, you can expect ~2-3k gas per loop. The following `read()` call costs an extra 2557 gas per item in the array

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract GasTesst {
    bytes32[] public test;

    function addToArray(bytes32 _t) public {
        test.push(_t);
    }

    function read() public {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            bytes32 t = test[i];
        }
    }
}
```